# Improving performance of serialization / hash function

Tags: c#, serialization, hash, hashtable

I'm working on a specialized on-disk hashtable (prior experiments with Berkeley, ManagedESENT, etc. didn't pan out). It has a fairly simple chained structure, with each key-value pair (KVP) followed in the file by a long (Int64) value that points to the next KVP in the chain (and uses a value of zero if there isn't one). I'm using MD5 to generate the hash code.

When profiling the code to assess the speed of adding entries, the hash function is responsible for about 55% of the running time, which isn't totally surprising. But about 25% of *that* time is coming from the `binForm.Serialize(ms, obj)` call in the `ObjectToByteArray` serialization function. Both functions are shown below. I'm assuming I can't make any big gains on the hash algorithm itself, but I'm wondering if I can eke some performance out of the serialization function?

```
    // Compute hash code
    long hash(object s)
    {
        byte[] y = md5.ComputeHash(ObjectToByteArray(s)); // Produces byte[16]
        long z = BitConverter.ToInt64(y, 0);
        long res = z & bitMask;
        return res;
    }

    // Convert an object to a byte array
    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        binForm.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you have to use a complex hash function such as md5. You can even use `ObjectToByteArray(s).GetHashCode()` because it doesn't have to be as `!unique!` as md5

Comment: That's interesting. In addition to any serialization gains I can get, I'll give it a shot and see if it speeds things up. Thanks.

Comment: And here is the performance comparisons of Json serializers + BinaryFormatter http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/fastJSON.aspx

Comment: I looked into fastJSON but couldn't figure out how it could be used as a binary serializer (i.e. how to produce a byte[]).

Comment: Of course, since it **not** a binary serializer. It convert your object to **Json string**  Then you can get byte[] as `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonstring)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use protobuf.net, found [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance), it's far quicker!

**Update**

From looking at your code I assume there is no requriement that computed hashes be consistent across AppDomains? If not computing your HashCode can be as simple as:

```
private static long GenerateHash(object key)
{
  long typeHash = key.GetType().GetHashCode();
  long keyHash = key.GetHashCode();
  return (typeHash << 32) + keyHash;
}
```

For future reference, your MemoryStream should really be in a using block, or else you run the risk of leaking memory:

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
      binForm.Serialize(ms, obj);
      return ms.ToArray();
    }   
}
```

Comment: it's actally quite slow from my experience.

Comment: @Alex, sorry your comment came in as I was updating... I assume you're referring to BinaryFormatter?

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I actually use Protobuf to serialize the KVPs, and it's great. But Protobuf can only serialize decorated "ProtoContract" classes, right? How can I use it to serialize an unknown object?

Comment: Wrt the update, that's correct. Very good idea. I will give it a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: If your `GenerateHash` method is just going to double-up the same 32-bit result of `GetHashCode` then you might as well save yourself 4 bytes and not bother doubling-up: you don't gain anything by doing it.

Comment: @Rich, Thanks! This works extremely well. I was able to improve my write performance by ~40%. I have to admit that I don't exactly understand what the getHashCode calls on the type and object instance are giving me, but I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: @Gadzooks34: **Be careful**: `GetHashCode()` does not need to produce the same value between restarts of your application, so identical matching items might not produce the same hashcode between two different runs of your app

Comment: @BrokenGlass very true (hence why I mentioned multiple app domains), however is probably worth mentioning that BinaryFormatter is not EVER guaranteed to produce the same results - it is only intended to get your data back intact, not provide a consistent data layout.

Answer (score 0):

binary formatter is known for its slow performance. try other methods of serialization.

Comment: Thanks - I agree, it's quite slow. But it's not obvious to me what better serialization alternatives exist (see above comment on Protobuf). Do you have any recs?